# show and hide div when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

When i click on a link, i want a div to become visible. However, i need to do this by knowing which link is clicked on, by checking which id it has. The content is hidden, but will not become visible when i click on a link. I am not allowed to use jquery. Any solution?

Javascript

```
function show() {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    if (a.id == "link1") {
        document.getElementByID("content1").style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else if (a.id == "link2") {
        document.getElementByID("content2").style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else if (a.id == "link3") {
        document.getElementByID("content3").style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else if (a.id == "link4") {
        document.getElementByID("content4").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}

function init() {

    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].className == "div") {
            divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    a.onclick = show;
}

window.onload = init;
```

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>Inl1-1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Uppg1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="meny" id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="link1">Utvärdering/Feedback</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="link2">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="link3">Öppettider</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="link4">Om Asperöd</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="div" id="content1">
        <p>Du kan kontakta oss på följande nummer:
            <br/>040-123456</p>
        <p>Du kan även mejla oss:
            <br/>aperöd@hotmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="content2">
        <p><b>Asperåd Äventyrsland</b>
        </p>
        <p>Växel: 0200-123456999 (kl.08:30-15)</p>
        <p>Stora Vägen 140</p>
        <p>289 22 Aperöd</p>
        <p>Skicka oss din <a href="Inl1-3.html">fråga</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="content3">
        <p>Vi har följande öppettider:</p>
        <p>Mån-Fre: 10:00 - 20:00</p>
        <p>Lör: 10:00 - 18:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="content4">
        <p>Asperöd är en fin park för alla möjliga personer. Vi erbjuder en massa,
            <br/>men det kostar 500kr för att delta för en dag.</p>
        <p>Asperöd är fylld med turister som besöker platsen minst en gång per månad.</p>
        <p>Asperöd är bland de största nöjesparkerna i Scandinavien.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a links object which provides the mappings.  Grab the target element from the event and store its id.  Then use the id to grab the proper element's id from the links object.

```
function show(event){
var links = {
    link1: "content1",
    link2: "content2",
    link3: "content3",
    link4: "content4"
};

for(var x = 0; x < links.length; x++){
   document.getElementById(links[id]).style.visibility = "hidden";
}

var id = event.target.id;
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
document.getElementById(links[id]).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

There is also an issue with the init function.  Since `a` is an array of elements you must iterate this array and bind the show function to the `onclick` event.

```
function init() {

    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].className == "div") {
            divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var x = 0; x < a.length; x++){
       a[x].onclick = show;
    }
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/538s2/

Comment: it does not work, and what bothers me is that i dont get any error in console

Comment: @DrWoolie see my update about iterating through the Array of anchors you retrieve.

Comment: Yes, now it worked. only one problem. the new content doesnt replace the old content when i click on a new link. is falls under it. do you know how i can solve this?

Comment: @DrWooolie See update. It just hides them all before displaying the selected one.

Comment: no, i am trying to search for the use of update, no luck at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
function show(a) {
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].className == "div") {
        divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
if (a.id == "link1") {
    document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else if (a.id == "link2") {
    document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else if (a.id == "link3") {
    document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else if (a.id == "link4") {
    document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

}

```
function init() {
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].className == "div") {
        divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].setAttribute("onclick", "show(this);");
}
```

}

Comment: welcome to SO. Please try improving the formatting of your answers to make them more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, your code works fine. But the problem is that the new content doesnt replace the old one.

Answer (score 1):

use   div.style.display = 'block'; div.style.display = 'none';

Comment: hidden works just fine. but i dont think thats where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in a different way. I've made some changes. you can copy and try this one

```
        <head>
<title>Inl1-1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-1.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Uppg1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show(id){


if(id == 'link1'){
document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else if(id == 'link2'){
document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else if(id == 'link3'){
document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else if(id == 'link4'){
document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
}

function init(){

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
  if(divs[i].className == "div"){
    divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
a.onclick = show;
}

window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="meny" id="menu">
<li><a href="javascript:show('link1')" id="link1" >Utvärdering/Feedback</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:show('link2')" id="link2">Kontakt</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:show('link3')" id="link3">Öppettider</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:show('link4')" id="link4">Om Asperöd</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="div" id="content1">
<p>Du kan kontakta oss på följande nummer: 
<br> 040-123456
</p>
<p> Du kan även mejla oss:
<br> aperöd@hotmail.com
</p>
</div>

<div class="div" id="content2">
<p><b>Asperåd Äventyrsland</b></p> 
<p>Växel: 0200-123456999 (kl.08:30-15)</p>
<p>Stora Vägen 140</p>
<p>289 22 Aperöd</p>
<p>Skicka oss din <a href="Inl1-3.html">fråga</a></p>
</div>

<div class="div" id="content3">
<p>Vi har följande öppettider:</p>
<p> Mån-Fre: 10:00 - 20:00 </p>
<p> Lör: 10:00 - 18:00 </p>
</div>

<div class="div" id="content4">
<p>Asperöd är en fin park för alla möjliga personer. Vi erbjuder en massa, 
<br> men det kostar 500kr för att delta för en dag.
</p>
<p> Asperöd är fylld med turister som besöker platsen minst en gång per månad. </p>
<p> Asperöd är bland de största nöjesparkerna i Scandinavien. </p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: i could use it, by i need to have the js code in a seperate file

Comment: then use the JS code in different file. what's the big deal. search for it how to use JS in different page